# Titanium problems receiving notifications

Tags: android, notifications, titanium, push

I am trying to subscribe cloud services using Titanium with Alloy.

I already configured the Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) API Key, and the ACM of my app, however in the cload.appcelarator.com push notifications sections appears: "Send a push notification to your subscribed devices.
You currently have 0 iOS clients, **0 Android clients subscribed to push notifications**. Any thoughts of this?

" This is the code with I'm testing with:

index.js

```
var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush');
CloudPush.retrieveDeviceToken({
    success: function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
        // Use this device token with Ti.Cloud.PushNotifications calls
        // to subscribe and unsubscribe to push notification channels
        Ti.API.info('Device Token: ' + e.deviceToken);
    },
    error: function deviceTokenError(e) {
        alert('Failed to register for push :(! ' + e.error);
    }
});
// These events monitor incoming push notifications
CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function (evt) {
    alert(evt.payload);
});
CloudPush.addEventListener('trayClickLaunchedApp', function (evt) {
    Ti.API.info('Tray Click Launched App (app was not running)');
});
CloudPush.addEventListener('trayClickFocusedApp', function (evt) {
    Ti.API.info('Tray Click Focused App (app was already running)');
});



$.index.open();
```

Thank you very much for any advise or help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some days trying... I already got Push notifications

index.js

```
// Require the module
var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush');
var deviceToken = null;

// Initialize the module
CloudPush.retrieveDeviceToken({
    success: deviceTokenSuccess,
    error: deviceTokenError
});
// Enable push notifications for this device
// Save the device token for subsequent API calls
function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
    deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
   // alert("--->" + deviceToken);
    subscribeToChannel();
}
function deviceTokenError(e) {
    alert('Failed to register for push notifications! ' + e.error);
}

// Process incoming push notifications
CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function (evt) {
    alert("Notification received: " + evt.payload);
});


// For this example to work, you need to get the device token. See the previous section.
// You also need an ACS user account.
// Require in the Cloud module
var Cloud = require("ti.cloud");

function loginUser(){
 // Log in to ACS
    Cloud.Users.login({
        login: 'YOURACSUSER',
        password: 'YOURACSPASSWORD'
    }, function (e) {
 if (e.success) {
            alert('Login successful');
        } else {
            alert('Error:\n' +
                ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
        }
    });
}
function subscribeToChannel(){
 // Subscribe the user and device to the 'test' channel
 // Specify the push type as either 'android' for Android or 'ios' for iOS
 // Check if logged in:
    Cloud.PushNotifications.subscribe({
        channel: 'test',
        //device_token: 'APA91bHRjGoZLCYKwn-XcCtNLETuf-KRKfT4sMgVE4KgXQgInYfZuYTNrZC7FUMugLs0idzzqtLytrvVJjVzYBzQoc7Q81hEerq0O2vww_tV8mACuUfAi0JRvs7LoufnQZpYLZrb_1rlUsIOEMsPxDs9b_pIRJF5rw',
        device_token:deviceToken,
        type: Ti.Platform.name == 'android' ? 'android' : 'ios'
    }, function (e) {
 if (e.success) {
            alert('Subscribed');
        } else {
            alert('Error:\n' +
                ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
        }
    });
}
function unsubscribeToChannel (){
 // Unsubscribes the user and device from the 'test' channel
    Cloud.PushNotifications.unsubscribe({
        channel: 'test',
        device_token: deviceToken
    }, function (e) {
 if (e.success) {
            alert('Unsubscribed');
        } else {
            alert('Error:\n' +
                ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
        }
    });
}



 loginUser();
```

in ti.app.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
    <property name="acs-api-key-production" type="string">XCLR6QnXrxQrDIx7OtI4DiHPr32qKTx3</property>
    <property name="acs-api-key-development" type="string">Sk77CE9ZJeA6eXohelrD9UKst7Ktgeph</property>
    <property name="acs-api-key" type="string">GOOGLE API</property> <!--API DE GOOGLE -->

    <id>com.creativa.petcare.ro</id>
    <name>PetCare</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <publisher>ricardo.orellana</publisher>
    <url>http://</url>
    <description/>
    <copyright>2015 by ricardo.orellana</copyright>
    <icon>appicon.png</icon>
    <fullscreen>false</fullscreen>
    <navbar-hidden>false</navbar-hidden>
    <analytics>true</analytics>
    <guid>254dae59-8688-45b6-9f82-331b6f378a85</guid>
    <property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">dp</property>
    <ios>
        <plist>
            <dict>
                <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone</key>
                <array>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                </array>
                <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
                <array>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
                </array>
                <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key>
                <false/>
                <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
                <false/>
                <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
                <false/>
                <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
                <string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
            </dict>
        </plist>
    </ios>
    <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
    <mobileweb>
        <precache/>
        <splash>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <inline-css-images>true</inline-css-images>
        </splash>
        <theme>default</theme>
    </mobileweb>
    <modules>
        <module platform="commonjs">ti.cloud</module>
        <module platform="android">ti.cloudpush</module>
    </modules>
    <deployment-targets>
        <target device="iphone">false</target>
        <target device="ipad">false</target>
        <target device="android">true</target>
        <target device="blackberry">false</target>
        <target device="mobileweb">true</target>
    </deployment-targets>
    <sdk-version>3.5.0.GA</sdk-version>
    <plugins>
        <plugin version="1.0">ti.alloy</plugin>
    </plugins>
</ti:app>
```

It would be a pleasure if this code can be helpful for any with the same doubt...